# remove the element in the array which is equal to any given targert

Tags: c++, algorithm

the full question is:

> Given an array and a value, remove all instances of that value in place and return the new length.The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the new length.

and there is my code.

```
int removeElement(int A[], int n, int elem) {   
    vector<int> B;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (A[i]!=elem) {
            B.push_back(A[i]);
        }
    }
    return B.size();
}
```

when i submit this code to the online judge, it tells me that I gave the **wrong answer**. The test case it responds with is:

```
Input: [4,5], 4 
Your Output: [4]
Expected Output: [5]
```

And i want to know why, i think it should be right, can anyone give me some enough reasons to let me understand?

Comment: "we should output" and "but expected" mean the same thing. I can't tell which is what the program outputs, and which is what the judge expects. But either case, the correct answer is [5], since you are supposed to remove all instances of 4 from the array. You don't remove anything from the array, you just move the non-equal elements into a vector and then *throw away the vector*.

Comment: This is a one-liner using `std::remove` and `vector::erase`.

Comment: @cdhowie is right, Given your description of the problem please OP review your question so as to get help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Because the argument is an array, it's actually just a call to `std::remove`.

Comment: @BillLynch It can be done even more efficiently than `std::remove`, since the order of the elements can be changed.

Comment: @BillLynch Yes, just `std::remove` will do it.

Comment: @larry david according to your codes the expected `return` from the function is `the size of  the vector` now how comes **the Expected output is [5]** if the inputs are [4,5] , 4?

Comment: @samuel Actually, the output is the in-place-modified `A[]` together with the new length.

Answer (score 2):

The request is that you remove all instances of that value **in place**, that is, modify the contents of the array pointed to by A. You need to return a new length so that the array `[A, A + new_length)` contains all elements that are not equal to `elem`.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how they want you to solve the problem. They have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
int main() {
    int array[2] = {4, 5};
    int length = 2;

    // Call the user's function
    int new_length = removeElement(array, length, 4);

    // Validate their output.
    assert(new_length == 1);
    assert(array[0] == 5);
}
```

Your code fails on the second assertion.